# Metro bundler stops after "Loading dependency graph, done"

Tags: android, react-native

I'm just starting to RN from ReactJs and I have been trying to run a React-Native Project, but when I type `react-native start` the Metro bundler stops at this line : `Loading dependency graph, done`.

I can notice this isn't right because it doesn't load my code changes and it gives me the error `"cannot connect to the development server"` after I reload the emulator.

I did some research and it should also tell that it is bundling a specific file 
something like this:

`BUNDLE [android, dev] ./index.js`

[current Metro bundler logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a932W.png)

I can only see the changes after I run "raect-native run-android"

react-native version:

`react-native-cli: 2.0.1
 react-native: 0.61.5`

I can provide more versions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

probably your device (emulator or physical) is not seeing your metro server running in your computer.

Try running in your terminal the adb reverse commando to map properly your device port with the same port for your metro.

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

I'm assuming you have your `adb` in environment path.

If this not work, just get you local ip address (with ipconfig or ifconfig, depending on your OS). and Shake your device. (Or hit `ctrl+m` or `command+m`, not sure if this is the shortcut), then a picker will show with some options..

Go to `Settings`, scroll down to `Debug server host & port device`, type your machine IP address, with the metro port running server (should be `8081`)... Example: `192.168.0.111:8081`.

This will try to find your machine and your metro server.

After you

Comment: Is pretty common, your RN app in dev, lost the path to your metro server. the adb command should be ran every time you restart your computer (or just add it to a npm script), and the thing in `Settings`, you should do again every time you delete and reinstall your app (since is just a Preference, saved to your app)

Comment: Shaking the device was a nice tip, it helped me.